# Pass specific method of a specific instance as parameter

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I would like to have a class where I can specify "*Instance a1 of A, you will call the function computeValue() of the specific instance b1 of B when you need the value*". I need to specify which method of which instance will be used by this instance.

So far I found two solutions :

The `eval()` solution :

```
class A {

  constructor(funcToCall) {
    this.funcToCall = funcToCall;
  }

  displayValue() {
    console.log(eval(this.funcToCall));
  }
}

class B {

  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  computeValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}


var b1 = new B(1);
var a1 = new A("b1.computeValue()");
a1.displayValue();// Displays "1", okay
```

The `function.call()` solution :

```
class A {

  constructor(funcToCall, instanceToCallItOn) {
    this.funcToCall = funcToCall;
    this.instanceToCallItOn = instanceToCallItOn;
  }

  displayValue() {
    console.log(this.funcToCall.call(this.instanceToCallItOn));
  }
}

class B {

  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  computeValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}


var b1 = new B(1);
var a1 = new A(b1.computeValue, b1);
a1.displayValue(); // Displays "1", okay
```

So to me the `eval()` solution seems very dirty and the `function.call()` seems better.

Which solution is the best ? Is there a more elegant solution to this problem ?

Comment: As a general rule, any time you have a choice between `eval()` and something else, choose something else. `eval()` should almost always be a last resort.

Comment: You can use `.bind()` to simplify the `.call()` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functions should almost always be preferred over `eval()`. You can simplify the second method by using `.bind()`, so you don't need to pass the function and instance separately.

```
class A {
    constructor(funcToCall) {
        this.funcToCall = funcToCall;
    }

    displayValue() {
        console.log(this.funcToCall());
    }
}

// class B is the same as yours

var b1 = new B(1);
var a1 = new A(b1.computeValue.bind(b1));
a1.displayValue();
```

Or if you still prefer to pass the instance separately, you can use `.bind()` in the constructor:

```
class A {
    constructor(funcToCall, instance) {
        this.funcToCall = funcToCall.bind(instance);
    }

    displayValue() {
        console.log(this.funcToCall());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is even more concise indeed !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that `eval` thing is *very* dirty and won't even work if `b1` is not in the proper scope. Using `call` is fine, but you can do better:

- Pass a combination of instance and methodname:

  ```
  class A {
    constructor(instance, methodName) {
      this.instance = instancen;
      this.methodToCall = methodName;
    }

    displayValue() {
      console.log(this.instance[this.methodToCall]());
    }
  }
  var a1 = new A(new B(1), "computeValue);
  ```
- Pass a function that does the method call and whatever else it needs on its own:

  ```
  class A {
    constructor(funcToCall) {
      this.funcToCall = funcToCall;
    }

    displayValue() {
      console.log(this.funcToCall());
    }
  }
  var b1 = new B(1);
  var a1 = new A(() => b1.computeValue());
  // or:   new A(b1.computeValue.bind(b1))
  // or anything else
  ```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, both your answer and Barmar' answer are answering my problem, so I've tick one them